# How do I make variables from a Python module available in Go?

Tags: python, go

I am building a tool in Go which needs to provide a way to resolve variables declared in the global scope of Python scripts. In the future I would like to extend this to Node.js as well. It needs to be cross-platform.

Basically, if someone were to have the following Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

hello = "world"
some_var = "one"
another_var = "two"
var_three = some_func()
```

I would like to have access to these variable keys and values in my Golang code. In case of the function, I would like to have access to the value it returns.

My current idea is to run the script with the Golang `exec.Command` function and have the variables printed to its stdout in some format (e.g. JSON), which in turn can be parsed with Golang. Thoughts?

Comment: If you want to copy environment variable sets around, I'd suggest the canonical NUL-delimited-list format used by `/proc/<pid>/environ`. It's easy to parse in *any* language, Python or Go included, and you don't need any custom tools to generate it if you're running on the Linux kernel, since the OS itself exports the set (at least, as it existed at process startup time).

Comment: (and if you *do* need to generate it yourself, `for k, v in os.environ.items(): print('%s=%s\0'  % (k,v), end='')` ain't hard).

Comment: I am not looking to work with environment variables here, just the variables defined in global scope of a Python script. Your comment did remind me that it needs to be cross platform.

Comment: I'm used to "exported" meaning "exported" *to the environment*, as performed by the `export` shell command, various `setenv()` calls, etc. If you're using it in a different context, it's not clear to me what the intent is.

Comment: What do you mean by "the information should remain in memory only" and "variables exposed by Python scripts"? Scripts don't expose variables - they just run, maybe print some stuff to stdout or stderr, and then exit with an integer return code. The way that that Python objects are stored in memory is not so simple for go code to just reach in and read them...

Comment: I edited my description to address the questions you have and added a small example of a python script that contains the variables to which I want access in Golang. I am not looking to intertwine Golang and Python at all, I just want to run the Python script with Golang and get the values of those variables in Golang after running the script. I hope this clarifies things!

Comment: Now, that sounds much more reasonable. So, you can just do as you originally suggested - json dump the relevant keys and values to stdout at the end of the Python script (you would need to modify the script directly, or write a wrapper around it)

Comment: They are of different runtime environments. Golang cannot directly access variables in Python's runtime. Vica versa. You can, however, program them to pass on variable values through standard I/O or environment variables. The key is to determine the proper format for information exchanges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are of different runtime environments. Golang cannot directly access variables in Python's runtime. Vica versa. You can, however, program them to pass on variable values through standard I/O or environment variables. The key is to determine the proper format for information exchanges.

For example, if the python script takes arguments as input and print the result, encoded as JSON, to the stdout. Then you can call the script with proper arguments, and decode the stdout as JSON.

Such as:

#### range.py

```py
import json
import sys

def toNum(str):
    return int(str)

def main(argv):
    # Basically called range() with all the arguments from script call
    print(json.dumps(list(range(*map(toNum, argv)))))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

#### main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func pythonRange(start, stop, step int) (c []byte, err error) {
    return exec.Command(
        "python3",
        "./range.py",
        fmt.Sprintf("%d", start),
        fmt.Sprintf("%d", stop),
        fmt.Sprintf("%d", step),
    ).Output()
}

func main() {
    var arr []int

    // get the output of the python script
    result, err := pythonRange(1, 10, 1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // decode the stdout of the python script
    // as a json array of integer
    err = json.Unmarshal(result, &arr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // show the result with log.Printf
    log.Printf("%#v", arr)
}
```

### Output global variables

To output global variables in Python as JSON object:

```py
import json

def dump_globals():
    # Basically called range() with all the arguments from script call
    vars = dict()
    for (key, value) in globals().items():
        if key.startswith("__") and key.endswith("__"):
            continue # skip __varname__ variables
        try:
            json.dumps(value) # test if value is json serializable
            vars[key] = value
        except:
            continue
    print(json.dumps(vars))

foo = "foo"
bar = "bar"

dump_globals()
```

Output:

```
{"foo": "foo", "bar": "bar"}
```

You can use a main() similar to the last one for this script:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func pythonGetVars() (c []byte, err error) {
    return exec.Command(
        "python3",
        "./dump_globals.py",
    ).Output()
}

func main() {
    var vars map[string]interface{}

    // get the output of the python script
    result, err := pythonGetVars()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // decode the json object
    err = json.Unmarshal(result, &vars)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // show the result with log.Printf
    fmt.Printf("%#v", vars)
}
```

Output:

```
map[string]interface {}{"bar":"bar", "foo":"foo"}
```

Comment: Exactly the solution that I created yesterday as well, but I accept your answer nonetheless as it is correct and works. The dump_globals() you demonstrated here is something I did not think about. It gave me the idea to provide a python module which exposes a function like that which users could simply import and call. Thanks!